# Power BI create a table based on a query, keeping filters on page

Tags: powerbi, dax

Say I have Query1, which looks like this:

```
date, origin, type, cnt 
5/1/2019, A, A, 6
4/29/2019, B, A, 6
4/29/2019, C, B, 3
```

And I have three filters on the report where users can define a date range, what origins, and types to consider.

Now I need to create a second table (DailyFiltered) that looks like this when no filters are applied:

```
date, filteredCnt
5/1/2019, 6
4/29/2019, 9
```

While considering what the user defines in the report filters. For example, if the user were to select only type A, then Daily Filtered would instead look like this:

```
date, filteredCnt
5/1/2019, 6
4/29/2019, 6
```

Currently, I have:

```
Daily Filtered = summarize(keepfilters(Query1), Query1[date], 
    "filteredCnt", sum(Query1[cnt]))
```

And I have Query1 and Daily Filtered joined on date, many to one, cross filter direction = Both.

The second table is only being filtered by the date filter for Query1. Not sure where I went wrong, but Daily Filtered is supposed to change when the front end user of the report toggles the origin or type filters.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what the problem is? You have created a second table, and connected it to the first table. So, what's the issue?

Comment: @RADO the second table only filters by the date, if I change the origins and types of the first query using the front end filters on the report, nothing happens to the second table.

Comment: Calculated tables (and columns) can not respond to filters. They are calculated only once - when you create them, and contain static data. If you want data to stay responsive to the filters, you must write **measures**.

Comment: I might be able to help you more if you define your objective in more general terms. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So I have one big query that has the number of data points grouped by the origin of the date the data point came in, the origin of the data point, and the type of data point. Then I need to create a histogram that shows the distribution of the data points based on the date range, origin, and type of data point defined by the user. So this report should adapt to the needs of the user, if the user is only interested in the distribution of data points that are type A, then he or she should be able to filter that out from the histogram. @RADO

Comment: So based on your last response, maybe what I need is a measure that calculates the total number of data points that meet all filtered criteria rather than a second table, but not sure how to write that.